# Is there a way in Chrome to "set" a tab to a hotkey and "return" to it when I press the key regardless of window?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm a chronic tab-opener, and I find myself frustrated with being unable to find the important tabs when I have multiple tabs and windows open.  What I'd like to be able to do is to "set" a hotkey to a particular tab (say, control alt T for a tab involving travel) so that when I press that key I can return to that tab regardless of what window.  I know about the Control + number and Control + Pgup/pgdown shortcuts, but I need something to quickly sort to relevant tabs, not just the next tab.  What is a good way of doing this that would allow me to quickly and painlessly re-map keys to tabs as I see fit, and delete the hotkeys when the browser closes?

Comment: If you pin your important tabs they will be grouped together on the left, making them easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

So I made [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-set-tab/gahnefhpekegjhmplnmgpfcaebipbhne) for you. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I am able to set a tab, I am unable to return to it.  I can check to see if other extensions are using alt + G, but I disabled one that was already, and nothing else is happening at that command.  Thanks for the effort, though! :)

Comment: I would suggest you to restart the browser after installation.